# Facebook share og:image can't load larger size image?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Open Graph for facebook sharing
But I got some question about the sharing.

If the pictures are too large, facebook will can't read the photo in share page.
I had add the below sentence in the page, and the debugger successfully load the photo in the table but it's not show in the share dialog.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://c.glassbean.com/images/uploads/abc.png?t=1" />
```

Is it have any size limit in the situation??  (The images are 1800-2500 x 1400-1700px)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**try the full image example so you can customize the dimensions :**

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

`Reference :` http://ogp.me/